# How do you say time like 1:45, 2:45, 3:45...?

Tags: time

If trains leave at 1:45, 2:45, 3:45, 4:45... how would you describe this in English?

I'm sure "Trains leave at every 45 minutes." is wrong, but I have no idea how to describe this.

Comment: https://www.vocabulary.cl/Basic/Telling_Time.htm     https://englishstudypage.com/grammar/telling-the-time-in-english/   https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/words/uhr.htm    In your case, trains leave 15 minutes before/to the hour, or at quarter to the hour.

Comment: I've downvoted your question because it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

*(The) trains leave **every hour** at **(a) quarter to the hour**.*

Or:

*(The) trains leave **hourly** at **(a) quarter to the hour**.*

[Travel information](https://www.fh-ooe.at/en/kongresse/2020/cross-cultural-business-conference/conference-venue/travel-information/)

Comment: In the UK it is reasonably common to hear '...at forty-five minutes past each hour'. An exact-minded person might add: 'the first leaves at six forty-five and the last at ten forty-five'.

Comment: 'Quarter to/past' tend to be favoured by people who learned to tell the time on clocks with hands.

Comment: Native speakers would very readily understand (in writing): 'Buses leave at xx:45 between 06:45 and 23:45'.